# NHibernate: Is MySql dialect mature and stable enough for use for large web app?

Tags: .net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, nhibernate

We are in the process of defining the architecture for new web app:

- ASP.NET MVC
- MySQL
- about 0.5 M unique visitors a day.
- .NET FW 4.0
- C# 4.0
- Search engine will probably be Sphinx (another option is Solr)
- Around 100 MB of new data in DB daily.

Is MySQL dialect for NH mature and stable enough for something like
this ?
Some things to be aware of when using NH with MySQL ?

I got the feeling that MSSQL is best supported with others little
behind ?
Do you have some references or personal experiences ?
What are other options for .NET <-----> MySql integration ?

EDIT: I added a bounty on this question. I would like some real world examples/experiences  of MySQL + NHibernate, open source projects, fallacies, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Sure it is.

If something of MySQL dialect (or even nhibernate) doesnt fit right for you (that's rare, IMHO) you still can use [hql](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-12-hql-the-hibernate-query-language#) to get more control about the generated queries, or even [native sql](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-14-native-sql#)

Also, NHibernate gives you another benefits, its stable and being used in a lot of big projects.

Comment: In addition to that, NHibernate makes it extremely simple to extend the dialect to add any missing functionality.

Comment: I know I can code native sql, but this is something that I would like to avoid as much as possible. If some corner of the app need special hanling that's OK. But for 98% of the cases I would like to avoid this. HQL is not a problem. I also have not the time nor the experience to add missing functionality in NH.

Comment: For example AFAIK MySQL doesn't support batching of commands. Don't know if this is problem of NH dialect, .NET driver for MySQL or MySQL itself.

Comment: It's a limitation of MySQL itself. but you can still have batching in .net: see http://www.reggieburnett.com/connectornet-5-2-now-supports-batching